# PHP: despite disabling all errors, copy() error message still displayed on page

Tags: php, error-handling

I have:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 0);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 0);
```

It seems to work but when I use `copy()` function and try to copy to directory with denied access the error is displayed on the page itself. I don't need it. But I can't intercept `copy()`'s errors. I tried `error_get_last()` and `try...catch (Exception $e)` but still can't intercept it? How can I disable showing copy errors on page and how to intercept them in code?

Comment: As short fix you can do `ob_start();copy(/*whatever*/);ob_get_clean();` that catches the output if any is produced while `copy`. Read about `ob_start()` :)

Comment: Thanks. My script starts with `ob_start()` and ends with `ob_end_flush()`;

Comment: Thats no Problem, because `ob_start()` is nested, so you can do that.# Read about it ;)

Comment: Like `ob_start(); print "Hello"; ob_start(); print "World";ob_get_clean(); ob_end_flush();` prints just 'Hello'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

from runtime it is better (and more reliable) to use:

```
error_reporting(0);
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php for more info.

also you can suppress any errors regarding of reporting level by prefixing expression with `@`:

```
@copy(...)
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php for more info, also note what this cause a performance drop and causes expression to return boolean false if error occured, regardless of its original return type.

**Worth noting:**

If you are using nginx+php-fpm (or similar) ini values may be overriden in php-fpm's pool configuration.

If you are using apache+mod_php ini values may be overriden in .htaccess file.

Check that, before resolving to `error_reporting(0)`, turning off error_reporting completely is not what you should do, as this may lead to broken logic (many popular libraries and frameworks rely on error reporting by setting handlers to traslate errors to exceptions).

In terms of portability use of error suppressing operator is preferred, dispite its affect on performance.

Answer (score 2):

If catching the copy error is all you need to do then:

```
set_error_handler(function ($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    // Log the error somewhere without spooking the users
    return true;
});
copy(...);

restore_error_handler();
```

This way you can "silence" only this error and keep everything else working as before.

Comment: I have both `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler` at the beginning of script. The problem is that in my case errors generated by `copy()` isn't visible to `error_get_last()`. I can see that `copy` returns `TRUE` or `FALSE` but can't get its message